# React router route loader not working on nested components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Am using react router v6 and i would like to use the new loader to load the data before the component loads. So i have the following

In my index.js

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="*"
           loader={async ({ params }) => {

               console.log("index loader log"); //this logs

               return true;
           }}
           element={<App />}
     > </Route>
  )
);
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

in my app component i have nested routes like

```
const App = () => {
 return (
     <>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="auth/*" element={<AuthLayout/>}/>
            <Route path="about"
             loader={async ({ params }) => {

               console.log("about child loader log"); //this doesnt log

               return true;
              }}
           element={<AboutPage/>}/>
        </Routes>
        <h1>Testing app</h1>
     </>

   );

 }
```

On the app component the loader on the `Route path="about"` does not console.log when i visit the about route but the component is rendered. What am i missing for the loader to work on the child route.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on some basic testing it seems that in order for the new RRDv6.4 data APIs to work you need to specify the complete routing configuration in the `createBrowserRouter` function.

There *does* however appear to already be an [issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9362) filed with `@remix-run/react-router` for this behavior as a reported bug, so you may want to follow it if it ever addressed/resolved. (*I suspect it was you since the name is "geoffrey" and the timing is coincidentally about an hour ago around the same time as this post*)

This above issue has since been [closed](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9362#issuecomment-1261060825) with comment:

> Descendant `<Routes>` trees do not participate in data loading
> (https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes) since they cannot
> be known ahead of render-time. You'll need to lift your descendant
> `route` definitions up into the routes you pass to `createBrowserRouter`.

The relevant information regarding the descendent routes and the new Data API can be found in the [`Routes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes) documentation in a note.

> Note:
>
> If you're using a data router like `createBrowserRouter` it is
> uncommon to use this component as it does not participate in data
> loading.

Hoist the entire route declaration to the parent creating the data router. The following does work with the loader function for the `"/about"` route and `About` component.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      path="*"
      loader={({ params }) => {
        console.log("index loader log");

        return "This is the App";
      }}
      element={<App />}
    >
      <Route path="auth/*" element={<AuthLayout />} />
      <Route
        path="about"
        loader={({ params }) => {
          console.log("about child loader log");

          return "this is the about page";
        }}
        element={<AboutPage />}
      />
    </Route>
  )
);
```

The `App` component should render an `Outlet` for the nested routes to render their content into.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Testing app</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-router-route-loader-not-working-on-nested-components]

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that changing from using `<Routes/>` to `<Outlet />` and specifying the whole routing configuration `createBrowserRouter` worked for me as a workaround.

Comment: Yes this does work by lifting the routes at the top.