# How can I structure my code to use a react router hook - (useLocation) inside a data router (createBrowserRouter)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I keep getting this error

`Uncaught Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.` How can I use the useLocation hook inside my component? I know I need to wrap my App in a Router but am not sure how to do that given that I need to use a data router.

```
    const App = () => {
      const location = useLocation();
      const previousLocation = location.state?.previousLocation;
    
      return (
        <RouterProvider
          router={createBrowserRouter(
            createRoutesFromElements(
              <Route location={previousLocation || location}>
                <Route
                  path="/"
                  element={<RootLayout />}
                  errorElement={<ErrorPage1 />}
                >
                  <Route index element={<Landing />} />
                  <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
                </Route>
                <Route
                  path="access"
                  element={<AppLayout />}
                  errorElement={<ErrorPage2 />}
                >
                  <Route
                    index
                    element={<AppHome />}
                    loader={usersLoader}
                    action={newUserAction}
                  />
                  <Route path="*" element={<NoMatchAppPage />} />
                </Route>
    
                {previousLocation && (
                <Route>
                  <Route path="start" 
                   element={<Modal />} />
                </Route>
              )} 
              </Route>
            )
          )}
        />
      );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What are you using the `location` reference for? It doesn't appear to be used in `App` . Move the `useLocation` lower in the ReactTree such that the router is above it and provides the routing context. If this isn't helpful to you to then please [edit] to clarify what exactly it is you are trying to do and provide a more accurate [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese I added some clarifying code that might help explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: @DrewReese I added some clarifying code that might help explain what I am trying to do. I am trying to create a modal that sits on top of the previously navigated route.  The previous location state is added in a react-router-dom Link so I can access using useLocation.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `App` component ***is*** the component rendering the routing context it can't itself use any RRD components or hooks that require a routing context to be provided from higher up in the ReactTree.

My suggestion here would be to create a layout route component that reads the current `location` value and provides `previousLocation` as a value from the rendered [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet)'s context provider. The `Modal` component would then use the [`useOutletContext`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context) hook to read the value to handle any conditional rendering logic.

Example:

```
const LocationLayout = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { previousLocation } = state || {};

  return <Outlet context={{ previousLocation }} />;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <RouterProvider
      router={createBrowserRouter(
        createRoutesFromElements(
          <Route element={<LocationLayout />}>
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={<RootLayout />}
              errorElement={<ErrorPage1 />}
            >
              <Route index element={<Landing />} />
              <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
            </Route>
            <Route
              path="access"
              element={<AppLayout />}
              errorElement={<ErrorPage2 />}
            >
              <Route
                index
                element={<AppHome />}
                loader={usersLoader}
                action={newUserAction}
              />
              <Route path="*" element={<NoMatchAppPage />} />
            </Route>

            <Route path="start" element={<ModalContainer />} />
          </Route>
        )
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

```
const ModalContainer = () => {
  const { previousLocation } = useOutletContext();

  ... business logic using previousLocation ...

  ... render `Modal` ...
};
```

Comment: I appreciate your approach. Your solution works for getting me the previousLocation data available to handle any conditional rendering. It took me a few days to understand. The issue I am having now - which I'm gathering is a different question - is now I can't use the loader and action in those routes that are being rendered in the modal container because they are now "descendent routes."  Here's the stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73875903/react-router-route-loader-not-working-on-nested-components) post on this. Still working through this problem.

Comment: @GarfieldMaytag Welcome, glad to help. Sorry I was out on vacation for a bit. Can you clarify what descendent routes you are referring to? The routes in both your post and my answer are just nested routes, which are in the data router and should be able to use all the data APIs.

Comment: No worries. I was on vacation and have been working on other aspects of this project. I'm actually still having trouble in the same spot. There's something I'm missing. I'm trying to implement a modal with the previous location as the back drop. If I use your logic, then I need to import the routes into the modal container. This is when you note: "business logic using previousLocation." This is where I need the router to render the different routes. When I import those routes/components I am not able to use the data APIs because they now become descendent routes.

Comment: this is the implementation I am going for. The challenge for me is that this implementation uses BrowserRouter and that does not support the Data APIs. I am using createBrowserRouter but that won't allow me to use this same approach.  https://blog.logrocket.com/building-react-modal-module-with-react-router/

Comment: @GarfieldMaytag Are you trying to implement something similar to the official [modal route with outlet](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/dev/examples/modal-route-with-outlet) demo/example? I've not ever understood that example, it doesn't make sense to me to couple the display of any modal component to the app routing. It's gets dicey when you want to show ***different*** routes under the modal. IMHO you should just completely decouple the modal UI from the routing. Either render the modal as part of some page's content, or make the modal a globally triggered component.

Comment: I do want the modal to be a globally triggered component. When the user clicks on the "Start Assessment" button regardless of the route they are on, it will trigger a modal which asks the user to confirm the student data before moving on to the actual assessment pages.  For some reason, I thought the approach presented on logrocket was easier because I could provide the data for the student via the Data API.  I can go back to the other approach and see how well that works.  The trick will be in getting the student data available in the modal.  I'll give this a try.

Comment: Thanks! I have it fully implemented using the decoupled modal UI you recommended, and I just used the Data APIs with some prop drilling to get the data that I needed in the modal. The last piece of this that I need to figure out -is how to prevent any interaction with the backdrop when I'm in the modal UI.  Do you have any recommendations for that?  I also realize that this question might best be taken to another post.  Thanks again!

Comment: @GarfieldMaytag Awesome, glad to hear you've something working out well. Yeah, I recall that if rolling your own modal component there's some  `body` element query selector logic to conditionally add some CSS rules to "lock" the content under the modal, but it's been a while since I have had to do that. Most UI libraries that offer a modal component will handle this part for you. And you are correct, this as a follow-on question would be better suited as a new post. If you create a new post feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can take a look when available.

Comment: Thanks! You're spot on. I'll probably ping you on if/when I post my next question. I have much more clarity on that question -which as you know -- is always a move in the right direction.

Comment: I got the issue with disabling the interaction with the backdrop solved using a pacakge. Seems like I had a css property interfering with the action when I had originally tried that solution.  On to the next issue!  Thank you again. I'm sure you'll hear from me again.